# Hosting Google Cloud App IP address on personal webpage

Tags: html, web, ip

I have setup a shiny server on Google Cloud and have it up and running: http://35.185.99.146:3838/AppTwo/

I would like to be able to host this on my personal website as some new pages. 
I have the html stored on GitHub.

*Please note, the personal website is learning for HTML, I have basically no knowledge in that area and I am not sure if this even the right question to ask regarding this.

TL;DR: Get http://35.185.99.146:3838/AppTwo/ to mywebsite.com/app1

Comment: To clarify, when you go to `mywebsite.com/app1` you’d like to see the content of that Google app, however there’s other stuff on `mywebsite.com` that does not come from Google? Then you probably want a reverse proxy setup on `mywebsite.com` for that path.

Comment: Correct.  For clarification, can you recommend any good resources for look into that?